# XML Validation against XSD nillable false for string types

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, schema

Currently I am using javax.xml.validation.Validator to validate xml against given xsd.

```
Sample xsd:
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="att1"/>
xml :
        <attr1/>
```

In above exmaple by default nillable will be false and minoccurs will be 1 for att1. When there is null value for att1, ideally validation should fail. But validation is going to success.

When i explicitly specify minlength for att1 as 1, then validation is failing. Is this the only way to achieve this? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have done it is correct. If you want to accept all strings except the zero-length string, then define a subtype of `xs:string` with minLength="1" and use this as the type of the `att1` element.

Forget `xsi:nil` and `nillable`. In XML the best way to represent missing data is with an absent element.